# Significato di "vuoi mettere" in questo passaggio

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Allora gli dissi che Cinto era sveglio e che per lui ci sarebbe voluta una cascina come la Mora era stata per noi. – La Mora era come il mondo, – dissi. – Era un’America, un porto di mare. Chi andava chi veniva, si lavorava e si parlava... Adesso Cinto è un bambino, ma poi cresce. Ci saranno le ragazze... **Vuoi mettere** quel che vuol dire conoscere delle donne sveglie? Delle ragazze come Irene e Silvia?...

Il mio dubbio è sul senso dell'espressione "vuoi mettere" in questo passo. Se ho capito bene quello che spiega il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mettere), "vuoi mettere" è un'espressione di uso familiare che si usa per indicare un paragone tra due cose «per rilevarne le eventuali differenze, spesso con l’opinione che una non possa reggere al confronto con l’altra». Tuttavia, nel testo citato non sembra esserci un paragone tra «quel che vuol dire conoscere delle donne sveglie» e un'altra cosa. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "vuoi mettere" in questo testo?

Comment: Il senso è quello che dici: qui, a giudicare da questo ristretto contesto, direi che il paragone implicito sia tra l'effetto positivo di “conoscere delle donne sveglie” e quello negativo di vivere in un posto più appartato, meno “porto di mare”, dove non passano ragazze del genere.

Comment: @DaG: Penso che tu abbia ragione. Potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A giudicare dal contesto fornito, direi che il significato sia proprio quello citato (un paragone in cui una delle due cose paragonate non regge il confronto con l'altra).

Qui, a quel che pare, il paragone implicito è tra l'effetto positivo di “conoscere delle donne sveglie” e quello negativo di vivere in un posto più appartato, meno “porto di mare”, dove non passano ragazze del genere.